# Pass params to controller using ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

It's my first time doing this, and I am a bit confused on how to pass params to a controller via ajax, and recreate the view with the new data.

So I have one `<%=link_to 'Today', [@project, @keyword] remote: true%>` (@project, @keyword) will redirect me to the same view, but how do I pass the param? which in this case will have to send a date (Date.today).

```
$ ->
 $("a[data-remote]").on "ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) ->
   alert "Success"
```

What do I need to add in that ajax response to recreate my view with new data.

Can someone help me with a good resource and applicable to rails 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this:

```
<%=link_to 'Today', [@project, @keyword], :date => Date.today, remote: true %>
```

It will pass the Today's date in `params` hash which you can use in your application.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass params as it was a normal link (eg :date => Date.today)

Controller will receive it in params, and should render a JS.erb file. Use JS to re-render the part of the view affected

$('#divaffected').html('<%= escape_javascript(render('a_partial')) %>')

Comment: I think is the easiest and more efficcient way, but you could modify the document using Javascript, reload the page (here Ajax have nonsense), ...